# jQuery animate() and slideUp at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to apply `animate()` and `slideUp()` functions to the same element. Both functions would start at the same time but would end at different times. How can I achieve that?

If I do

```
$(el).animate(200);
$(el).slideUp(2000);
```

The `slideUp` function waits for `animate` function to finish.

Thanks

Comment: Both `.animate()` and `.slideUp()` will add the requested effect to the end of the animation queue for the element in question unless you specify `queue:false`. What is the actual animation you want to do? `$(el).animate(200)` doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run two fx at the same time, you can pass "queue: false" as an argument like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="el"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.el {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.el')
    .animate({'left' : '100px'}, 500)
    .slideUp({duration: 1000, queue: false});
```

This code will slide the element right for .5 seconds, while at the same time sliding it up for 1 second. Here's a jsfiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/cWLvc/